# Class design question (Disposable and singleton behavior)

Tags: c#, wcf, oop, singleton, dispose

The `Repository` class has singleton behavior and the `_db` implements the disposable pattern. As excepted the `_db` object gets disposed after the first call and because of the singleton behavior any other call of `_db` will crash.

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
 public class Repository : IRepository
 {
    private readonly DataBase _db;

    public Repository(DataBase db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public int GetCount()
    {
        using(_db)
        {
            return _db.Menus.Count();
        }
    }

    public Item GetItem(int id)
    {
        using(_db)
        {
            return _db.Menus.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);
        }
    } 

  }
```

My question is, is there any way to design this class to work properly without removing the singleton behavior? The `Repository`class will be serving big amount of requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you supply a `DataBase` instance to the `Repository`, this means creation and disposal is not in the scope of the `Repository` class. Therefore, `Repository` should not dispose that instance. You should remove the `using` statements, and you'll be fine. Write the `Repository` as follows:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly DataBase _db;

    public Repository(DataBase db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public int GetCount()
    {
        return _db.Menus.Count();
    }

    public Item GetItem(int id)
    {
        return _db.Menus.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);
    } 
}
```

Comment: As the Repository class acts like a singleton, keeping a long running context is a bad practice. It may grow very fast in memory consumption.

Comment: I agree that keeping the context running for a long time is a bad practice. In that case you've got two options. 1. Don't use the `Repository` as a singleton and return a new instance on each request. 2. Pass the `DataBase` class on each call to the method. I'd go for option 1. Don't forget that next to the dispose problem, you need to make sure your `DataBase` is thread-safe when you return the `Repository` as a singleton (when you're in a multi-threaded environment).

Comment: if keeping a long running context is a bad practice why is it a singleton?

Comment: Because of performance. The Repository class will be serving big amount of requests.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
using(_db)
```

you are guaranteeing that Dispose() will be called on your object.

I would suggest changing this to use a static class with a private static member for _db.

```
public static class Repository {
  private static DataBase _db; 

  // static constructor
  static Repository () {
    _db = new Database();
  }

  public static int GetCount() {
    return _db.Menus.Count();
  }
  public Item GetItem(int id) {
    return _db.Menus.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);
  }
}
```